# Moq, test method return error - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

I have following service:

#### The `DocumentTypeService` class

```cs
public partial class DocumentTypeService : IDocumentTypeService
{
    private readonly IRepository<DocumentType> _documentTypeRepository;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public DocumentTypeService(IRepository<DocumentType> documentTypeRepository, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _documentTypeRepository = documentTypeRepository;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public virtual async Task<IList<DocumentType>> GetAll()
    {
        var query = from t in _documentTypeRepository.Table
            orderby t.DisplayOrder
            select t;
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

#### The test agains `GetAll()` method

```cs
[TestClass()]
public class DocumentTypeServiceTests
{
    private Mock<IRepository<DocumentType>> _documentTypeRepositoryMock;
    private DocumentTypeService _documentTypeService;
    private Mock<IMediator> _mediatorMock;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Init()
    {
        _mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
        _documentTypeRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository<DocumentType>>();
        _documentTypeService = new DocumentTypeService(_documentTypeRepositoryMock.Object, _mediatorMock.Object);
    }


    [TestMethod()]
    public async Task GetAllDocumentTypes()
    {
        await _documentTypeService.GetAll();
        _documentTypeRepositoryMock.Verify(c => c.Table, Times.Once);
    }
}
```

#### The error that the `GetAllDocumentTypes()` method returns

> Test method Grand.Services.Tests.Documents.DocumentTypeServiceTests.GetAllDocumentTypes threw exception:
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
> Stack Trace:
> Queryable.OrderBy[TSource,TKey](IQueryable'1 source, Expression'1 keySelector)
> MongoQueryable.OrderBy[TSource,TKey](IMongoQueryable'1 source, Expression'1 keySelector)

**UPDATE:**

```cs
/// <summary>
/// MongoDB repository
/// </summary>
public partial class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a table
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IMongoQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get { return _collection.AsQueryable(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to test? That an exception is thrown when `_documentTypeRepository.Table` is null? If not, you'll need to setup `_documentTypeRepository.Table` to return a non-null value

Answer (score 2):

You should mock the following method call:

```
_documentTypeRepository.Table
```

Specifically, you need something like this:

```
_documentTypeRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository<DocumentType>>();
var mongoQueryableMock = new Mock<IMongoQueryable<DocumentType>>();
_documentTypeRepositoryMock.Setup(x=>x.Table).Returns(mongoQueryableMock);
```

Doing so, when `_documentTypeRepository.Table` is called would return an empty list of `DocumentType` and no need for OrderBy to be called. The default behavior is, since you don't mock this call, `_documentTypeRepository.Table` returns null. Hence the null pointer exception later on.

In order to understand the latter argument, you should be aware of how the query syntax works compile-wise. Query syntax is just syntactic sugar. When you code is compiled, it is replaced first by the equivalent ("LINQ") method calls, and the the corresponding IL code is generated. So your query:

```
from t in _documentTypeRepository.Table
orderby t.DisplayOrder
select t;
```

would be first transformed in a query like the following one:

```
_documentTypeRepository.Table
                       .OrderBy(x=>x)
                       .Select(x=>x)
```

and later on the corresponding IL code would be generated based on the latter query.

So, if `_documentTypeRepository.Table` returns null, then calling `OrderBy` would throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you. 
property Table returns IMongoQueryable<DocumentType>. 
I updated quetion with code Repository.cs. 

How me return value in mock object?

Comment: @StefanHansch You are welcome. Please check my update and let me know. Thanks

Comment: get error: ` Test method Grand.Services.Tests.Documents.DocumentTypeServiceTests.GetAllDocumentTypes threw exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Stack Trace: Queryable.OrderBy[TSource,TKey](IQueryable1 source, Expression1 keySelector) MongoQueryable.OrderBy[TSource,TKey](IMongoQueryable1 source, Expression1 keySelector) `

Comment: @StefanHansch did you fix it? I saw that you marked the answer as the solution and I assumed that you fix it.

Comment: not yet. But it's additional question.  I created new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879412/unit-testing-with-imongoqueryable-system-invalidcastexception-unable-to-cast-o

Can you please too check.

Comment: @StefanHansch will check it as some point. But I would suggest, you un-mark it as the answer, since this would be misleading for the readers of your post :)