# Unit Testing with IMongoQueryable. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type EnumerableQuery to type IOrderedMongoQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have following Service with method GetAll() and I wrote test testing this method.

```
public partial class DocumentTypeService : IDocumentTypeService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<DocumentType> _documentTypeRepository;
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public DocumentTypeService(IRepository<DocumentType> documentTypeRepository, IMediator mediator)
        {
            _documentTypeRepository = documentTypeRepository;
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        public virtual async Task<IList<DocumentType>> GetAll()
        {
            var query = from t in _documentTypeRepository.Table
                        orderby t.DisplayOrder
                        select t;
            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }
       
    }
```

This my test method GetAllDocumentTypes():

```
[TestClass()]
    public class DocumentTypeServiceTests
    {
        private Mock<IRepository<DocumentType>> _documentTypeRepositoryMock;
        private DocumentTypeService _documentTypeService;
        private Mock<IMediator> _mediatorMock;
        private Mock<IMongoQueryable<DocumentType>> _mongoQueryableMock;
        private List<DocumentType> _expected;
        private IQueryable<DocumentType> _expectedQueryable; 

        [TestInitialize()]
        public void Init()
        {
            _mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
            _documentTypeRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository<DocumentType>>();
            _mongoQueryableMock = new Mock<IMongoQueryable<DocumentType>>();
            _expected =  new List<DocumentType>
            {
                new DocumentType() {Name = "name1", Description = "t1", DisplayOrder = 0},
                new DocumentType() {Name = "name2", Description = "t2", DisplayOrder = 1}
            };
            _expectedQueryable = _expected.AsQueryable();
            _mongoQueryableMock.Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(_expectedQueryable.ElementType);
            _mongoQueryableMock.Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(_expectedQueryable.Expression);
            _mongoQueryableMock.Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(_expectedQueryable.Provider);
            _mongoQueryableMock.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(_expectedQueryable.GetEnumerator());
                                  
            _documentTypeRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Table).Returns(_mongoQueryableMock.Object);
            _documentTypeService = new DocumentTypeService(_documentTypeRepositoryMock.Object, _mediatorMock.Object);
        }

        
        [TestMethod()]
        public async Task GetAllDocumentTypes()
        {
            var actual = await _documentTypeService.GetAll();
            Assert.AreEqual(_expected.Count, actual.Count);
        }
    }
```

Get error:

```
Message: 
    Test method Grand.Services.Tests.Documents.DocumentTypeServiceTests.GetAllDocumentTypes threw exception: 
    System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Grand.Domain.Documents.DocumentType]' to type 'MongoDB.Driver.Linq.IOrderedMongoQueryable`1[Grand.Domain.Documents.DocumentType]'.
  Stack Trace: 
    MongoQueryable.OrderBy[TSource,TKey](IMongoQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector)
    DocumentTypeService.GetAll() line 38
    DocumentTypeServiceTests.GetAllDocumentTypes() line 101
    ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

Could you please explain me why type is not IOrderedMongoQueryable and how solve this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**NEW (2020-09-15)**

I reproduced your effort as nearly as I could. There are two problems.

First, your `GetAll()` method includes an `orderby`, which is what's forcing `IMongoQueryable` to become `IOrderedMongoQueryable`. However, `_mongoQueryableMock` doesn't return `IOrderedMongoQueryable`. And if you try replacing `_mongoQueryableMock`'s  `IMongoQueryable` with `IOrderedMongoQueryable`, that fails, too. I didn't find a way to get `_expectedQueryable` to allow an `IOrderedQueryable`.

Second, Async is probably going to give you trouble. Without Async, I can change the `GetAll()` query to something like this, which resolves the query before applying the orderby:

```cs
   public List<DocumentType> GetAll()
   {
       var query = from t in _documentTypeRepository.Table.ToList()
                   orderby t.DisplayOrder
                   select t;
       return query.ToList();
   }
```

However, I didn't find a way to manage the ToListAsync.

All in all, I'm back to my original advice. Don't try to mock IMongoQueryable. Change the service to accept MongoClient. Either way you're mocking Mongo, but accepting IMongoClient you're using it directly instead of hiding it behind another abstraction.

```cs
        private readonly IMongoClient _mongoClient;
        public DocumentTypeService(IMongoClient mongoClient) {...}
```

**ORIGINAL (2020-09-14)**

I can't be completely sure, but I believe it's because `_documentTypeRepository` isn't returning `IMongoQueryable`. It's returning a `Table`, which will force an ordered mongo queryable.

For this to work using the mocking method described by me [here](https://www.softwaremeadows.com/posts/mock_returning_a_list_as_imongoqueryable_for_unit_testing/), `_documentTypeRepository` would either need to return IMongoQueryable *then* convert to `Table`, or see if IQueryable can convert to `IOrderedMongoQueryable`.

In short, nothing is mocking the return of `IOrderedMongoQueryable`.

Honestly, what this all points to is that the repository is probably too tightly coupled to the implementation. Forcing `IMongoQueryable` to `IQueryable` is a code smell and anti-pattern. You might consider rethinking your service and/or repository layer in one of two ways:

1. Create an `_documentTypeRepository.GetAll()` method that maps the MongoDb results to `DocumentType`. OR
2. Don't use a repository pattern in the service. Instead, inject the IMongoClient, return the data from Mongo as part of the `GetAll` method, and map to DocumentType there.

Comment: Thanks.I have following setup to return correct value of Table: _documentTypeRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Table).Returns(_mongoQueryableMock.Object);